# How to share domain classes and business rules between client and server like in RIA Services by writing them only once

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf, client-server

In an ASP.NET - WCF application I want to share domain classes and business rules between client and server without rewriting them, just like in Silverlight RIA Services. Collecting these in one assembly and referencing this from client and server can solve the problem, but how: by adding service refence to client will generate these classes in client proxy, without any behaviour (methods). How can I achive this?

NOTE: RIA Services will not be used.

EDIT: After some Googling I came across CSLA.NET. Can it solve this issue?

Comment: Why do you not just use RIA services?

Comment: Hi Shiraz, 
Shortly, Silverlight will not be used.

Comment: WCF RIA services is not just for silverlight.

Comment: oh i didn't know that, thanks. i think i should have explaned the requirements a bit more. does ria requires server and client projects to be in the same solution or at least additional assembly reference, which we do not prefer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok here is how I've done it: As blowdart said I put all the domain code that I want to share between server and client into a seperate assembly. Then I had both server and client referencing to this shared assembly. Then added service reference to client, with one exception: In  add service reference dialog there is a button "Advanced". There I have checked reuse types in referenced assemblies. This way I had all proxy goodies, asynchronous method calls etc., generated for me.

Answer (score 3):

You avoid using the client proxy altogether.

So first off, put your contract classes into a shared assembly, and add a reference to the project in both the server and client programs. In the client you can then use ChannelFactory to create a connection to the WCF service and exchange data; something like

```
ChannelFactory<IServiceContract> factory;
factory = new ChannelFactory<IServiceContract>("");

IServiceContract proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
using(proxy as IDisposable)
{
   proxy.MyMethod();
}
```

Comment: hi blowdart, by not adding proxy class we are deprived of asynchronus methods and other utulities if there are any. i will update this thread as soon as i find any solution to the problem.

Comment: You could of course wrap the calls in background worker threads or massage the async behaviour in other ways.

Comment: @arch, you can create a sub interface of  your serivce interface on the cleint and add the "BeginXXX" methods your self"